# working on django development server but not on apache

Tags: python, django, apache, url

i am facing an issue with the apache server, we have written the code, in which if the url entered in the form field is valid it will display an error message, when i run the code through django developement server it works fine, displays the error message, but when running through apache, then does not show the error message just returns back to that page itself. here is the code below of both the python and the html:

---

```
objc= {
    "addRecipeBttn": "/project/add",
    "addRecipeUrlBttn": "/project/add/import",
    }

def __showAddRecipe__(request):
    global objc
    #global objc
    if "userid" in request.session:
        objc["ErrorMsgURL"]= ""
        try:
            urlList= request.POST
            URL= str(urlList['url'])
            URL= URL.strip('http://')
            URL= "http://" + URL

            recipe= __addRecipeUrl__(URL)

            if (recipe == 'FailToOpenURL') or (recipe == 'Invalid-website-URL'):
                #request.session["ErrorMsgURL"]= "Kindly check URL, Please enter a valid URL"
                objc["ErrorMsgURL"]= "Kindly check URL, Please enter a valid URL"
                print "here global_context =", objc
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/project/add/import/")
                #return render_to_response('addRecipeUrl.html', objc, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
            else:
                objc["recipe"] = recipe
                return render_to_response('addRecipe.html',
                    objc,
                    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        except:
            objc["recipe"] = ""
            return render_to_response('addRecipe.html',
                objc,
                context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        login_redirect['next']= "/project/add/"
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/project/login")



def __showAddRecipeUrl__(request):
    global objc
    if "userid" in request.session:
        return render_to_response('addRecipeUrl.html',
            objc, 
            context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        login_redirect['next']= "/project/add/import/"
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/project/login")
_
```

The HTML file:-

kindly check and let me know if anyone can help on this issue, its working on django development server.

Thank you
Suhail

Comment: Why are you using "global"? The dict "objc" is accessible in your (by the way ugly double underscore) methods.

Comment: You app under apache works as wsgi, proxy, mode_python deployment method?
See apache error logs.
Do not use print for debuging.
Do not use empty except in try block. You code can rise exception in try blok like KeyError and others

Comment: And you should definately consider using django.forms, so you never need to do all this stuff manually. There are such nice things as URLField which can check for a correct url automatically if you like. Please DO read the forms documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/#forms

Comment: i removed the global, still its not working on apache server, its working on the django development, checked the apache error logs, no error there.

Comment: There shouldnt be any need to use globals in django like that! Your problems possibly arise because in your deployment you have more processes/threads running, while with the dev server only one and you probably run into a problem with that! Another thing to improve in your code: Use reverse() to get the urls you need (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse), no need to hardcode anything of that like you do!

Comment: hi, 
how can check for the process threads in the apache server, i just have this one python website, is it because other people are accessing the pages and because of that the process/threads are increasing, can you help me know, how can i resolve this.

thanks.

Comment: You generally shouldn't use `__double_underscore__` methods in your code: they are normally special methods invoked indirectly by syntactic sugar. For example, the built-in `len()` function calls an object's `__len__()` function.

Comment: i have corrected on that, removed the double underscores and tested, still the same.

Comment: @Suhail, of course it's still the same. Please consider a complete overhaul of this code - there are too many ugly parts in it to describe them in a short time. Furthermore: lazerscience mentioned that you better not use globals - _maybe_ these are one of the reasons why it's not working in a production environment (which always uses threads or multiprocesses)

Comment: @Suhail if you need further assistance post your changed code for review!

Answer (score 1):

hey guys, thanks for the support, the issue is resolved, i did it this way.

```
def showAddRecipe(request):
    #global objc
    if "userid" in request.session:
        objc["ErrorMsgURL"]= ""
        try:
            urlList= request.POST
            URL= str(urlList['url'])
            URL= URL.strip('http://')
            URL= "http://" + URL

            recipe= __addRecipeUrl__(URL)

            if (recipe == 'FailToOpenURL') or (recipe == 'Invalid-website-URL'):
                #request.session["ErrorMsgURL"]= "Kindly check URL, Please enter a valid URL"
                objc["ErrorMsgURL"]= "Kindly check URL, Please enter a valid URL"
                print "here global_context =", objc
                arurl= HttpResponseRedirect("/project/add/import/")
                arurl['ErrorMsgURL']= objc["ErrorMsgURL"]
                return (arurl)
            else:
                objc["recipe"] = recipe
                return render_to_response('addRecipe.html',
                    objc,
                    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        except:
            objc["recipe"] = ""
            return render_to_response('addRecipe.html',
                objc,
                context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        login_redirect['next']= "/project/add/"
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/project/login")
```