# Django url/page displayed with development server but not apache server

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm working on Django 1.11, the URL,

`http://djangoserver:8002/dj/dev/userlogin/789`

works with development server, but with apache URL:

`http://djangoserver/dj/dev/userlogin/789`

it throws `Page not found (404)` error.

Regex used for the URL is : 
`url(r'^[0-9]+$', views.userlogin.login , name='login'),`

The reset of pages are displayed properly.

I have tried solution posted in the following posts which did not work for me:
[django application works on development server but I get 404 on Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622488/django-application-works-on-development-server-but-i-get-404-on-apache)

[working on django development server but not on apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021418/working-on-django-development-server-but-not-on-apache)

[django production server: root path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415055/django-production-server-root-path)

I'm not using any virtualhost.My httpd.conf file code snippet:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /dj /var/www/html/dev/dev/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess djangoserver  python-path=/var/www/html/dev

WSGIProcessGroup djangoserver

WSGIScriptAlias /dj /var/www/html/dev/dev/wsgi.py process-group=djangoserver

<Directory /var/www/html/dev/dev >
#       Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/dev/dev_app/static/
<Directory /var/www/html/dev/dev_app/static/ >
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Could be usefull if you post here your Apache Configuration file (at least, the VirtualHost file you are using)

Comment: @jeasoft I have added the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only change I made is to  declare WSGIScriptAlias along with process-group in httpd.conf file, code snippet:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess djangoserver  python-path=/var/www/html/dev

WSGIProcessGroup djangoserver

WSGIScriptAlias /dj /var/www/html/dev/dev/wsgi.py process-group=djangoserver

<Directory /var/www/html/dev/dev >
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/dev/dev_app/static/
<Directory /var/www/html/dev/dev_app/static/ >
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `/dj` as the the alias for your Django application, that means your Django app receives the path `/dev/userlogin/789`, not `/dj/dev/userlogin/789`. On your dev server that's the path that works, so you should change your Apache configuration to:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/dev/dev/wsgi.py
```

So that `/dj` is still part of the path parsed by your application.

Comment: I have tried this solution, it does not work. With out any alias, django throws 404 error. Even if url file states :       url(r'^dev/', include('dev_app.urls',namespace='dev_app',app_name='dev_app')),
    url(r'^dj/dev/', include('dev_app.urls',namespace='dev_app',app_name='dev_app')),

Comment: Do you know if the 404 is thrown by Apache or Django? Check your logs.

Comment: Would help then to show us the error, what URL is it trying to match?

Comment: The error thrown is: Using the URLconf defined in dev.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^dev/
^dj/dev/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: that's when trying to fetch `/dj/dev/userlogin/789`? The error says django received an empty path... Note also that your WSGIScriptAlias should be at the end (if using `/`) in order to catch the static alias.

Comment: Yes, it did give that error. The workable solution that I found is that I declared WSGIScriptAlias only once, commented the first one,kept second declaration.